# kable whitespace when writing to docx

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable

I can't quite figure out how to get some whitespace into the cells of a table when writing to word. I hate word but unfortunately, I have to use it.

This is essentially what I hoped would work:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=TRUE}
library('magrittr')
tibble::tibble(
  wowie = c('A', '   B', '\tC')
) %>% 
  knitr::kable(
    format = 'markdown',
    escape = TRUE
  )

```
````

But instead we just get all this whitespace removed. Any suggestions on how to indent specific cells a bit?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any suggestions on how to indent specific cells a bit?

`&nbsp;` (non-breaking space), `&ensp;` (en space) and `&emsp;` (em space) are used in HTML and word processing to create multiple spaces and can be combined together.

````
```{r setup, include=TRUE}
library('magrittr')
tibble::tibble(
  wowie = c('A', 
            '&nbsp;B',           # add one space
            '&ensp;C',           # add two spaces 
            '&emsp;D',           # add four spaces
            '&nbsp; &emsp; F')   # add more spaces (combined together)
) %>% 
  knitr::kable(
    format = 'markdown',
    escape = TRUE
  )

```
````

Output:

[image]